# Restarting network controller on Windows Azure Virtual

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, azure

During an RDP session to a Windows Azure virtual machine I inadvertantly disabled the network controller and now am not able to access the server. I tried restarting the server in hopes that it would enable the controller, but that is not the case.  Is there a way to re-enable the network controller?

Thank you,
Euris

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the network working again, by changing the size of the server. This caused the virtual machine to be rebuilt, which implies a new network controller for the virtual machine. I then changed the machine size back to the original size. Thanks to Steve Espinosa for the suggestion.